# Graphics2D - Text is HUGE in scaled coordinate space

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

The first "foo" is normal, but the second one is so huge I can only see the base of the "f". The font-size is the default.

```
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
    Shape ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
    g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
    g2.drawString("foo", 100, 100);
    g2.scale(500.0f / length, 500.0f / length);
    g2.drawString("foo", 1, 1);
```

Changing the font size will not help because it only allows `int` sizes and the size that would make sense for the scale is something like `0.02`.

The reason I need to draw the text while in scaled space is because I am drawing a grid of nodes and I want to scale the coordinates to the number of nodes in each dimension. That way I do not have to do complicated calculations.

I need the text to label the edges.

**Update:** I am able to get the text by doing the following sequence each time I want to draw the text: saving the transform, translating to the desired location in scaled space, unscaling, drawing the text at `(0, 0)`, and restoring the transform.

Comment: What is the type and value of `length`?

Comment: @megadan value could be anywhere from `2` to `1000`, integers

Comment: You're losing the fractional part by dividing two integers instead of floats or doubles.

Comment: @megadan thank, but that is not the central problem.  I will edit the question to avoid the confusion. The value of `length` as I am testing is 10 and it divides perfectly but the text is still huge.

Comment: If your drawing a grid, couldn't you just translate the Graphics context instead if scaling it?

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks. True, but then I have to track the radius of the nodes as a variable so that I can use different sized bitmaps to render. Say 1000x1000 vs 200x200. Scaling allows me to use constants for everything, from line-width to circle radius, etc.

Comment: Drawing the text at the point `(0, 0)` will still leave descenders dangling, e.g. `"syzygy"`.

Comment: The problem is, scaling doesn't just affect the translation matrix, it affects everything, so your scaling will change the "scale" of font/graphics which is rendered after it...

Comment: @trashgod descenders are perfectly fine. i am doing a translate, scale, draw the text, unscale, untranslate.  so it is not (0, 0) on the original canvas. works perfectly fine, i tested "syzygy"

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am undoing the scale after drawing the text. I save the result of `g2.getTransform()`, then do `g2.scale(...)` etc., then set the saved result back into `g2.setTransform(original)`. So the stuff that happens later works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Font method

```
public Font deriveFont(float size)
```

to obtain desired font size font. Guess the 0.02 shoud be fine.